# JSR233 Sampler - unable to return the value to a user-defined variable

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, jsr233

I have this piece of code from the website to masked and encrypt a password that I'm trying to create in jmeter using JSR233 sampler

```
function getControlPrefix() {
        var a2 = document.forms[0].a2.value;
        var a2n = "";
        for(var i=0; i < a2.length; i++){
            a2n += "*";
        }

        var type="DATABASE";
        a2 = encrypt.AESEncrypt(a2, "SL1LXZP20GGGL262QIVWYURY", 256);
            document.forms[0].a3.value = a2; 
        document.forms[0].a2.value = a2n;  
        document.forms[0].txtResFrac.value=screen.width;
        if (getControlPrefix.prefix){
            return getControlPrefix.prefix;
        }
```

I have defined a user-variables in the Thread Group (a2 = Password_1, a3 = ''). These parameters are the password and enrypted password from the website.

Using the JSR233 sampler, I tried to replicate the code above using this:

```
def a2 = vars.get('a2') 
def a2n = "";  

for (var i=0; i < a2.length(); i++) 
 {a2n += "*";}  

//vars.put('a2',vars.get('a2')); 

vars.put('a2','a2n'); 

println("This is the user's password: a2 "+a2); 
println("This is the user's masked password: a2 "+a2n);
```

I am able to successfully generate the masked password and I can see it in the console correctly like this

```
This is the user's password: a2 Password_1  
This is the user's masked password: a2 **********
```

But in the debug sampler I'm seeing it as a2= a2n instead of the one below

```
a2 = **********
```

What should I do to get the value (**********) instead of a2n?

I'm expecting the value of the variable will be returned instead of the variable itself.

Comment: `vars.put('a2','a2n')` remove the quotes around `a2n` - you want the value not the string

Comment: @cfrick In the actual script I placed the above code in the JSR223 Pre-processor. I'm able to see the * in the debug sampler, jmeter.log and console but when I check the server.log to see if it is sending the * in the password field, I'm still seeing a2n. Any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You made either a mistake or a typo, you need to change this line:

```
vars.put('a2','a2n');
```

to this one:

```
vars.put('a2',a2n);
```

because you're setting the value of `a2` JMeter Variable to literally `a2n` String instead of the object value.

More information:

- [Groovy Strings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)